# Use iconv directly on the selected region to convert codes

Tags: c

I copied and pasted the C code as:

```
int main(void)
{
   statements
   return 0;
}
```

to org's babel code block, when strike  C-c C-c, it report error:

```
/tmp/babel-uaYVXU/C-src-Pd1SZs.c:11:6: error: stray ‘\240’ in program
   11 |    statements
      |      ^
/tmp/babel-uaYVXU/C-src-Pd1SZs.c:12:1: error: stray ‘\302’ in program
   12 |    return 0;
      | ^
```

Then I have to create a new file and employ iconv to tackle the problem as:

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//translit input.c > output.
```

Is it possible to use iconv directly on the region of selected codes?

Comment: `C-u M-x shell-command-on-region`?

Comment: It would be simpler of course if you could eliminate those characters from the program text in the first place. They did not magically appear: somebody put them there.